# Count open tabs in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tabs, internet-explorer-11

I have a requirement that I limit IE11 to only opening 1 tab.  Apparently this was configurable in previous versions of IE but now it is not in IE 11.  I was hoping to find a way to do this with javascript.

Essentially, my idea is this:
Make my page with this javascript the default homepage for when the browser is opened.  On the first page the javascript would interrogate the browser and realize there is only one tab open and do nothing.  If the user clicked on new tab, then my page would load in that tab, interrogate the browser and see there is already a tab open and close this tab (not the other tab, which would obviously be a security issue).

That's it, I just need to know if another tab is open.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API available in the browser to allow such a thing, it's simply impossible to do.